# Read a "." separated file and create a SQL query using python

Tags: python, sql

Input file:

```
sch1.ft1
sch1.ft2
sch2.ft3
sch2.ft4
```

Query:

```
def get_tables_columns(filename):
    res_dct = {}
    with open(filename) as f:
        for line in f:
            line = line.strip()
            cols = line.split('.')
            res_dct = {cols[i]: cols[i + 1] for i in range(0, len(cols), 2)}
    return res_dct

tables = get_tables_columns("SchemaTable.txt")
print(tables)

def get_sql(schema, table):
    statement = "select colno, colname, typename, length from syscat.columns where tabschema ='{0}' and tabname ='{1}' order by colno ".format(schema,table)
    return statement
```

Output from the function I wrote: `{'sch2': 'ft4'}`

I need to build a query using key and value like `{sch1:fact1, sch1:fact2, sch2:fact3, sch2:fact4}`.

Desired SQL:

```sql
the requirement is if the sql runs for 
`select tabschema, tabname, colno, colname, typename, length from syscat.columns where tabschema ='sch1' and tabname ='ft1' order by colno`
the output should be stored in sch_ft1.txt. like wise for all the contents in input file.
```

**is it possible to store the output of each sql in diff file. for example if the code is running for  `select colno, colname, typename, length from syscat.columns where tabschema ='sch2' and tabname ='fact4' order by colno`  i need the contents to store in sch2_fact4.txt file like wise for rest of the queries**

Comment: Could you please explain what you have tried and what is not working? SO is primarily a knowledge platform. It'd be great if you prepare a question such that others can benefit as well.

Comment: i used one function to convert list to dict and use it in another func for sql preparation

Comment: What are you expecting your final query(output of get_sql) to look like? You have only given the output of get_tables_columns function. Also are you always going to require only the first 2 records in the schema file? Please edit your question with these details for completeness.

Comment: kindly reopen the question please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

{sch1:fact1, sch1:fact2, sch2:fact3, sch2:fact4} is not a valid dictionary as a dictionary needs to have unique keys.
You can call the get_sql function from within the get_tables_columns function to construct the query for each line that is read.

This code should give your desired output. It will write the queries to a file called query.txt

```
def get_sql(schema, table):
    statement = "select colno, colname, typename, length from syscat.columns where tabschema ='{0}' and tabname ='{1}' order by colno ".format(schema,table)
    return statement
def get_tables_columns(filename):
    res_dct = {}
    output = open("query1.txt", 'a')
    with open(filename) as f:
      for line in f:
        line = line.strip()
        cols = line.split('.')
        query = get_sql(cols[0], cols[1]) + "\n"
        with open(line + ".txt", 'w+') as my_file:
          my_file.write(query) 
    output.close()
    return res_dct
get_tables_columns("SchemaTable.txt")
```

Comment: thank you so much. can you help by making me save the output ina  file?

Comment: Your welcome. See the revised code above.

Comment: i want output of each row sql in each file..sch1.ft1.txt, sch.ft2.txt etc

Comment: Please see modified code

Comment: this prints the sql in file. what about its output to the file

Comment: can i have the output in separate files?